# C File Handling Appending Random Characters into File

Tags: c, file-handling

The following block of code creates a string

```
void generateDot(struct node **head, char *str){
    if(*head == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        struct node *itr = *head;

        generateDot(&(itr->left), str);
        if(itr->parent){
            char buff[3];
            snprintf(buff, 3, "%d", itr->parent->data);
            strcat(str, buff);
            strcat(str, "--");
            snprintf(buff, 3, "%d", itr->data);
            strcat(str, buff);
            strcat(str, "\n");
        }
        generateDot(&(itr->right), str);
    }
}
```

The following block of code writes the string to the file:

```
 char str[] = "";
 generateDot(&head, str);
 printf("%s", str);

 FILE *fhand = fopen("1.dot", "w");
 fputs(str, fhand);

 fclose(fhand);
```

When I am printing `str`, it prints as expected. However, even though the same `str` is being printed into the file, the second line of the file shows unexpected characters, regardless of what `str` is.

For example, when `str` is:

```
3--1
7--3
3--4
19--10
7--19
19--20
```

The file contains:

```
3--1
`F
w
3--4
19--10
7--19
19--20
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `char str[] = "";` create `str` with **1-character of storage** containing `'\0'`. Rule: *Never Skimp on Buffer Size*. If you think your max is 2-chars (3 with the nul-terminating char), then `char str[16] = "";` will suffice (or `str[32]` and guarantee handling all 64-bit integer values with room to spare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `strcat(str, buff)` you're writing to adjacent, unallocated memory. This invokes undefined behavior, anything could happen.

When you print `str` the memory happens to be as you've written. But something in `fopen` and `fputs` allocates some more memory which overwrites the unallocated parts of `str` with garbage.

You need to allocate sufficient memory to `str`. Since you don't know how much memory is needed, you'd be better off doing the allocation and reallocation inside `generateDot` and return the string.

Comment: Allocating a large enough size to `str` worked for me. Thanks.